# Iterate Through a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that accepts a string parameter that represents a Spanish-language sentence and returns a new string that is, respectively, a translation of the English-language sentence.

According to the exercise I have, I have to translate every word in a sentence using the dictionary words that appear in the translate function.

```
def translate(sentence):  #  the function start here
words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 'el': 'the'}
```

This is the way to call a function, calling a function has the value of the sentence to be translated :

print(translate("el gato esta en la casa"))

Your ideas on how I approach the problem
I tried alone without success

Comment: you didn't get an acceptable answer from all the posts on this site with the exact same title?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? please, share your attempts.

Comment: try  to yield but  it  give me  all key from the dict And not in the correct order of the sentence to be translated

Comment: you already wrote everything you need in the dictionary.. just break the string to words and give them the value of their key in the dictionary

Comment: The generator is supposed to work on the library and take away only the words that are in the sentence that have a function call

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to iterate over the sentence, not the dictionary. In most cases, if you need to iterate a dictionary you are probably doing something wrong.

```
def translate(sentence):  #  the function start here
    words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 
             'el': 'the'}
    return ' '.join(words[english_word] for english_word in sentence.split())
```

This will take in passed in Spanish sentence, split it to a list of words (splitting on whitespace), look up each word in the dict then put back everything together into a string using whitespace as a delimiter.

Of course this is a naive solution that will not care about correct grammar. or about missing words (hint: use `try-except` or `dict.get` to handle the latter).

```
print(translate("el gato esta en la casa"))
# the cat is in the house
```

Comment: I need to combine a generator .

Comment: @saar this contains a generator. Do you know what a generator is?

Comment: The generator is supposed to work on the library and take away only the words that are in the sentence that have a function call

Comment: General question, shouldn't a generator include the  "yield " ?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 'el': 'the'}


def translate(sentence):
    splitted_sentence = sentence.split()
    return ' '.join([words[word] for word in splitted_sentence])

print(translate("el gato esta en la casa"))

>> the cat is in the house
```

Comment: were  is  the generator?

Comment: Again, where is the generator in your answer?

Comment: Is there a generator here?

Comment: @saar you never specified you needed one? In your question you said it should return a string.

Comment: I have noted that it is necessary to use a generator ,If I wasn't clear enough then apologize

Comment: General question, shouldn't a generator include the  "yield " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple dictionary lookup using `get` so, you can handle `KeyError`:

```
def translate(sentence):  #  the function start here
    words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 'el': 'the'}
    return ' '.join(words.get(x, '') for x in sentence.split())
```

Comment: using `.get(x, '')` can lead to very funny results

Comment: As I wrote, i must use the generator in  this  exercise

Comment: @DeepSpace, if not OP wants to ignore them completely.

Comment: @saar, This is using generator comprehension with `join`, though a list comprehension would be more faster.

Comment: @Austin can you elaborate why you believe that a list comp will be faster than a genexp here?

Comment: @DeepSpace, `join` is a special case where it is expecting values in one shot. Generator is lazy which again slows down the process in the `join` context.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary works this way  : `dictionary["key"] = value`.

for your code I would suggest using the words in your sentence as keys. you will then get the values.

for example : `words["el"] = "the"`

```
def translate(sentence):  #  the function start here
    ret = ''
    words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 'el' : 'the'}
    for w in words:
        ret += words[w]+" "
    return ret
translate("el gato esta en la casa")
```

Comment: */9-+5620/*-89+562./7123/

Comment: The generator is supposed to work on the library and take away only the words that are in the sentence that have a function call

Answer (score 0):

```
def translate(sentence):  #  the function start here
    words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 'el': 'the'}

    english_words = sentence.split()
    for word in english_words:
        yield words[word]

result = translate("el gato esta en la casa")
for res in result:
    print (res,end= " ")
```

I don't get why do you need a generator for this but whatever

this prints: `the cat is in the house`

just a small note since I see you asked some people if a generator needs the 'yield' part, the answer is no.

```
def translate(sentence):  #  the function start here
    words = {'esta': 'is', 'la': 'the', 'en': 'in', 'gato': 'cat', 'casa': 'house', 'el': 'the'}

    english_sentence = (words[word] for word in sentence.split())
    return type(english_sentence)

print(translate("el gato esta en la casa"))
```

this prints out: `<class 'generator'>`

basically if you " ".join(english_words) you will get the sentence you want